# How to use an if condition inside a list comprehension?

Tags: python, reduce

I have a `reduce` function that looks like this:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, [foo(x) for x in listValue], [])
```

I also have another function called `goo` and I want to use it when `x` achieves some condition, for example `x >= 10` inside the reduce .

My idea is something like:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, [foo(x) for x in listValue if x < 10 else goo(x)], [])
```

but that gives me an error:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, [foo(x) for x in listValue if x < 10 else goo(x)], [])
                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

`for` and `if` are in the wrong order. You first need to specify the `if`, then the `for`.

Use this `reduce` in your code:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, [(foo(x) if x < 10 else goo(x)) for x in listValue], [])
```